# Java Map to capture a JSON object vs specific Java class. Performance?

Tags: java, json, performance, dictionary

Our system receives a ton of data as JSONs (Lets say 2 individual, and 1 array of 12 JSONs. All this for each entity in the organization, 45K+ entities). Each one of these JSONs has about 30 to 50 attributes.

Currently we're parsing all these 12 JSONs and keeping them as a maps, so we end up with 45K * 12 = 540K JSONs, each of which have 30 to 50 attributes.

After processing all of these, they are written back to a audit trail file, so that we have a copy of all the JSONs that were used.

When I profile this application, a major chunk of time and memory seems to be spent in `String --> JSON(Map)` conversion and `JSON(Map) --> File` Stream again. There are a ton of Map & Set "Node" objects getting created, iteration garbage that gets generated, etc. All in the area of set/map maintenance as the captured data grows.

I could probably improve CPU in the 2nd part by keeping the original JSON strings and just write them back, but Im curious about another aspect of this.

If I were to use specific classes: `IndividualOne.java`, `IndividualTwo.java` and `ArrayElem.java` (12 instances per entity go on to the array), so that the incoming JSON gets converted into instances of these classes rather than Maps, would that vastly improve performance? Or not as much?

I will try a pilot project to see what happens, but before I do that I thought I'll pose the question in the community to see what others experience has been in this regard.

Thanks.